# Windows Defender Firewall is blocking sendgrid

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I setup sendgrid to use web api (instead of smtp relay) to send email.
I followed the instructions on C# how to send email including creating the api key environment variable and installing nuget package sendgrid.

After calling client.SendEmailAsync(msg) the response of returned is "Accepted" which says everything is working. But no email was received on the my test email.

After turning off Windows Defender firewall, email was sent. So I think firewall is blocking sending my email?

My question is, how can i add exception settings for sendgrid in the firewall to allow outgoing emails from sendgrid or are there configurations both in sendgrid or firewall that i missed?

The code:

```
        var apiKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SendGridApiKey");
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Example User");
        var subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        var to = new EmailAddress("my_outlook_email_here", "Example User");
        var plainTextContent = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
        var htmlContent = "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with C#</strong>";
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
```

I added port 25 and 587 to inbound rules and outbound rules both for TCP and UDP to open the ports in windows firewall, but email cannot be send still.

Comment: Allow your smtp ports 25 and 587. It will work.

Comment: SMTP is a type of HTTP which has special character the must be encoded (see : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).  The email is probably failing because you are not encoding the special characters.  You can use System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(string) to do the encoding.  Can you explain what your email contains.  Any attachments and what mode are you using.

Comment: I updated above with my code to include contents of the email

Comment: @jdweng SMTP is not a type of HTTP. It has nothing to do with HTTP. SMTP was invented a long time before HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

While this is an old question I had a similar problem with my firewall.  I had to allow HTTPS transport from the sendgrid server (outgoing interface) to my DMZ (incoming interface, where my website is located).  The address that is used for sendgrid from my server 54.155.98.0.